# Spotfire - Batch of user password

Tags: spotfire

We have a high amount of user and I need to update the password and the current process is going to Administration manager, then search for the user and change the password, so I want to know if there is a way to do it on a batch using a script that call an external file to get the password and user that I need to change I mean like having a list and then export it to spotfire

Answer (score 3, accepted):

unfortunately I can't find a way to batch update users in Spotfire Server. if you needed to import a bunch of new users, you could use the [command line interface](https://docs.tibco.com/pub/spotfire_server/7.5.0/doc/html/TIB_sfire_server_tsas_admin_help/GUID-65B25CB4-44DB-4CCB-85B7-B89471E112B1.html), but it doesn't look like the `import-users` command will "overwrite" existing users (it should report an error when trying to add a new user who already exists).

I believe the password field in the Spotfire database is Base64 encoded, so you could theoretically run a database update query but **this is really dangerous and may wreck your database**. if you try anything like this, be sure to work in a test environment and be doubly sure that you have backups!

my recommendation is to use something like LDAP. the Spotfire database is not really designed to administer large number of users, or at least it doesn't seem that way from an administrator's perspective.

Comment: There's unfortunately no way of doing this in bulk through scripting or use of UIs. It can be done through the various APIs however (most suited is probably the SOAP Web Service API).

And yes, using LDAP or similar is a good recommendation for other things than POCs or small department deployments.